# How to Snap to a curved object

Tags: modeling

Im trying to make a heatshield design..
and i made a test cylinder with full heatshield, and i did that manually rotating, then dublicating..

[image]

But now that i want to do it on a nose cone, i have no idea how to get it to snap and curve with the nose cone shape.

[image]

ive tried using an array modifier,

ive also tried to shrink wrap it, both of these to no success

im sorta a beginner to blender, but i know the basics and how to get around.

Comment: if the cone is another object you can try to give a Surface Deform modifier to your grid with a cylinder as Target then shrinkwrap your cylinder to the cone. Or directly deform your grid with a lattice?

Comment: The whole nose cone is one thing, the grid part and the interior looking part is all one thing

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that my vertical bars are your grid object. I've also created a cone. Create a cylinder (here I display only its wireframe to keep the cone visible), give it the same radius as your grid, give it some horizontal subdivisions:

[image]

Give your grid (here, my bars) a *Surface Deform* modifier with the cylinder as Target, click on the *Bind* button. Now give the cylinder a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the cone as *Target*, the cylinder will stick to the cone surface and the bars will follow:

[image]

Comment: the actual nose cone itself was not made in blender, it was brought in from somewhere else, so its all one thing,

all i want to do is find a way to fill the whole nose cone up with these little tiles...(https://i.imgur.com/EwYjl3t.png)

and have them all follow the contours of the nose cone, and wrap around it nicely.

as an example of what im trying to do : (https://i.imgur.com/Cozw6Iy.png)

Comment: so what about my solution? Also if the cone is completely hidden by the tiles, do you really need a cone under the tiles cylinder? can't you just use a lattice to deform?